# Change color of the "X" icon

Tags: input, colors, icons, ionic3

I can not change the icon color "X" linked to this input of ionic:

```
<ion-input placeholder="Seach" clearInput ></ion-input>
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: That element have `.searchbar-clear-icon` class. The "X" icon is an image background so you should change it via `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.text-input-clear-icon** class to override the css properties

```
  .text-input-clear-icon {
       background-image: url("imagePath")!important;
     }
```

Basically ionic adds a background-image in the **.text-input-clear-icon**
which represents the **X** icon/symbol you see.
so by simply overriding the background property, you can have your custom icons in place of the default one

You can also refer to the this link
[change placeholder and clear-icon color for ion-search bar not globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783470/change-placeholder-and-clear-icon-color-for-ion-search-bar-not-globally)